# Perform soft delete in Many to Many mapping - JPA - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity

```
class EntityA {
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "entity_b",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_c_id"))
    @JsonView(Views.ALL.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<EntityC> mappings;
  }
```

I dont have delete permission on this database instead we use soft delete.

I definded an entity_b

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "entity_b")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE entity_b SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE id=?")
public class EntityB extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "entity_a_id")
    Long entityAId;
    @Column(name = "entity_c_id")
    Long entityCId;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    Boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```

When I try to update the EntityA and update the mappings I expected this to call the @SQLDelete query for deleting but its executing the actual DELETE operation.

Is it possible to override the DELETE operation. Across the whole project for all entities or individuial entities, both solution are okay.

Note: I was able to solve with manually handling the deletion instead of letting jpa does it, but ius it possible that I could do it minimal code and I also have multiple such ManyToMany relationships. Looking for a generic solution that can apply across the project

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. 'When I try to update the EntityA and update the mappings' - which mappings? You haven't shown any mappings from `EntityA` to `CourseTags`

Comment: This should be tagged Hibernate as it is not jpa. Except for a missing filter so you don't see the entities marked as deleted, what you've shown looks correct.  Looking at the code here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-soft-delete which has a working, runable test case, how is your project different? Maybe run it and step through the differences, and turn on logging to compare as maybe something is preventing that annotation from being picked up, you have other errors or warnings you are missing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that your expectations are wrong, as you've double mapped the "entity_b" table.

The CourseTags entity and its @SQLDelete query apply when you remove CourseTags entity instances - via EntityManager.remove(courseTag) calls. If you try that, you should see it working.

What you must be doing is trying to remove `List<EntityC> mappings` references. This is a ManyToMany relationship which is also set to use the "entity_b" table, but completely independently of the CourseTags entity. None of the settings on CourseTags apply to the ManyToMany; removing a reference will just immediately cause JPA to clean up (aka delete) the row in the join table.

If you want to have additional state in there (you have an ID and is_deleted in there), you should probably treat it as an entity - and only as an entity.

In EntityA, use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<EntityB> mappings;
```

While in B:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "entity_b")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE entity_b SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE id=?")
public class CourseTags extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id")
    EntityA entityA;
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_c_id")
    EntityC entityC;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    Boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```